# websocket set protocol and origin

Tags: go, websocket

i use this lib: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket
how to set protocol and origin,

code :

```
func InitWSSClient(url1, protocol, origin string)  {
    u := url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: url1}

    fmt.Println(url1,u.String())
    d :=websocket.DefaultDialer


    //c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
    c, _, err :=d.Dial(u.String(),nil)
    var limit int64 =1024 * 1024 *32

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dial:", err)
    }
    c.SetReadLimit(limit)

    go readWSMessage(c)
    go sendWSmessage(c)

}

func readWSMessage(ws *websocket.Conn) error {
    for {
        _,message,err := ws.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log15.Error("receiveWebsocket ", "error", err)
            panic("error")

        }
        assignmentWebsocket(string(message))
    }
}

func sendWSmessage(ws *websocket.Conn) error {
    for {

        select {
        case params := <-WebsocketParams:
            fmt.Println("ws send messages", params)
            err :=ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage,[]byte(params))
            if err != nil {
                log15.Error("receiveWebsocket ", "error", err)
                panic("error")

            }
        }

    }

}
```

x.net.websocket  set these element like this :

```
websocket.Dial(url, protocol, origin)
```

how to achieve this function in gorilla/websocket/, ths you help.
i try many solutions is not working. if you know any solutions,

found the solution:

```
d := websocket.DefaultDialer
d.Subprotocols = []string{protocol}
header :=http.Header{}
header.Set("origin",origin)
```

Comment: You should answer to your own question and put your solution there. So that, it will be easier for someone with the same problem to find your solution.

Comment: @horex, I did not enable this setting when I asked. I will pay attention to it later. thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution, you can set like this

```
u := url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: url1}
d := websocket.DefaultDialer
d.Subprotocols = []string{protocol}
header := http.Header{}
header.Set("origin", origin)
c, _, err := d.Dial(u.String(), header)
```